# Cannot display points with jogl by vertex2i

Tags: jogl

I've read a lot of guide with using jogl.. But I have the same problem with all demo-apps...

When I start a simple App with jogl and try to display 3 points with coordinates (0,0), (10,15) , (100,150) for window with dimenstion 500x500, I can see only the (0,0) point. But if I divide coordinates in 100 then I'll be able to see all points... Why there is a huge scale and how it can be off?

```
import javax.media.opengl.*;
import javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class SimpleApp implements GLEventListener {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GLProfile glp = GLProfile.getDefault();
        GLCapabilities caps = new GLCapabilities(glp);
        GLCanvas canvas = new GLCanvas(caps);
        canvas.addGLEventListener(new SimpleApp());
        canvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));

        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.getContentPane().add(canvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
                new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        frame.setVisible(true);
                    }
                }
        );
    }


    @Override
    public void init(GLAutoDrawable glAutoDrawable) {

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose(GLAutoDrawable glAutoDrawable) {

    }

    @Override
    public void display(GLAutoDrawable glAutoDrawable) {
        GL2 gl2 = glAutoDrawable.getGL().getGL2();

        gl2.glColor3d(1,0.5,1);
        gl2.glBegin(GL.GL_POINTS);
        gl2.glVertex2i(0,0);
        gl2.glVertex2i(1,1);
        gl2.glVertex2i(1,2);
        gl2.glEnd();
    }

    @Override
    public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable glAutoDrawable, int i, int i2, int i3, int i4) {

    }
}
```

Comment: You should avoid legacy OpenGL

Answer (score 0):

Your points must be in your view frustum. The use of JOGL requires a clear understanding of computer graphics like for OpenGL. You can look at my simple example [here](https://gist.github.com/gouessej/3420e2b6f632efdddf98). You should learn how to setup the viewport, the projection matrix and the model-view matrix.

Moreover, questions specific to JOGL should be asked on [its official forum](http://forum.jogamp.org).